# Ctrl+d does not reapeat when held down

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout, hotkeys

I'm using mac osx. I used [Ukele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) to remap Ctrl+D to delete. It deletes character at the cursor. But does not repeat when I held the keys as it does when I held the delete key. How do I do that?